# How to show user name and profile picture in Futter using Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am written code for getting the user name and the profile picture.

I have gotten the document ID already.

Terminal:

```
Restarted application in 425ms.
flutter: DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(UserData/yKorLkbVK5jIGlWIti95)
```

Also I worked on the UI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZIgz.png)

setting.dart

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:Meucci/FireAuth/getUserData.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Setting extends StatefulWidget {
  const Setting({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Setting> createState() => _SettingState();
}

class _SettingState extends State<Setting> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  List<String> documentID = [];

  Future getDocumentID() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
            print(element.reference);
            //documentID.add(element.reference.id);
          }),
        );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getDocumentID();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 50),

            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.purpleAccent, width: 3)),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.white),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent[100],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Signed In as: ' + user!.email!),
                Material(
                  child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                      },
                      color: Colors.purpleAccent[100],
                      child: Text('Sign Out'),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

getUserData.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class getUserData extends StatelessWidget {
  final String docId;
  getUserData({required this.docId});

  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(docId).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text('${data['name']}');
        }
        return Text('Loading..');
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Setup in CloudFirestore]

Is there any method to display the username as text using FutureBuilder?

How can I add a profile image in by using the image URL in CloudFirestore and show the user name below the circular shape container?

Comment: try to use provide function

Answer (score 0):

To display user name you can try below snippet, get the user profile information as explained in this [document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/manage-users/#get-a-users-provider-specific-profile-information) and use the `Text` widget to display user name on flutter app.

Example:

```
Text("Hi ${currentUser.displayName}")
```

To display profile picture get the [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) of your stored photo. Then you can take the downloaded URL, store it in a variable and output it with `Image.network(photoUrl)`.

For more detailed information you can check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KurjrXR5mRg) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66418195/18265570)